# get_post_meta and add_post_meta not working

Tags: post-meta

I have a code like below but it returns the `false`. There is data in `$ggowlccpy_transaction_details_capture` and the order id is being correctly passed. This is for woocommerce order meta.

I don't know why it is getting saved.

```
<?php
$ggowlccpy_transaction_details_capture = array(
    'merchant_ref'    => $ggowlccpy_order_id,
    'transaction_id'  => $ggowlccpy_response['transaction_id'],
    'transaction_tag' => $ggowlccpy_response['transaction_tag'],
    'method'          => $ggowlccpy_response['method'],
    'amount'          => $ggowlccpy_response['amount'],
    'currency_code'   => $ggowlccpy_response['currency'],
    'positionofsave'  => 'captured',
);

update_post_meta(
    $post->ID,
    '_ggowlccpy_trasaction_capture',
    $ggowlccpy_transaction_details_capture
);

add_post_meta(
    $post->ID,
    '_ggowlccpy_refund_details_get',
    base64_encode( serialize( $ggowlccpy_transaction_details_capture ) )
);

$data = get_post_meta(
    $ggowlccpy_order_id,
    $key = '_ggowlccpy_refund_details_get',
    $single = false
);

$tb_meta_unserialized = unserialize( base64_decode( $data ) );

error_log( var_export( $tb_meta_unserialized, 1 ) );

echo $tb_meta_unserialized;
```

Comment: Which bit returns false? It's the wp_postmeta table.

Comment: `get_post_meta( $ggowlccpy_order_id,` - no, that should be the post ID not the order ID. So that's what's failing: you actually want to search the post meta for a serialized value and you don't know the post ID? That's not get_post_metae.

Comment: @Rup, you should make it an answer.

Comment: @MaxYudin Thanks, but the answer would be how to do that search correctly. And I don't have a good solution for that. I'd guess you'd have to save the order ID in a separate post meta value, or leaving it as-is do a LIKE search for the ID and then unserialize all the results to see which ones actually match.

Comment: @Rup I think that's the mistake I am making. I don't wherein database it saved. Let me have a test again

Comment: I don't know much about WooCommerce, now it's likely a general WordPress function's syntax. But there (in Woo) should be the table where relations between products and orders have to written in (it's off-topic here). Now it's up to OP to figure out where is the problem. It seems you've pointed to the right place.

Comment: @Latheesh, WooCommerce's database tables are off-topic here until they are not native WordPress tables. @ Rup pointed you to the right code line.

Comment: @MaxYudin yeh.. I have changed my question

Comment: @Rup Thank you It is the correct answer. I have changed the question please make it as the answer . I understand where I was making a mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're saving the transaction details as a serialized object in post-meta and then you're trying to search for a specific order ID. Your problem is here:

```
$data = get_post_meta( $ggowlccpy_order_id, $key = '_ggowlccpy_refund_details_get',
                       $single = false );
```

[`get_post_meta`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) requires a post ID but you're passing it the order ID you want to search for.

How to search for the order ID? The problem is that it's packed into a serialized object. One way would be to also store the order ID as a separate meta value so that you can search for it directly, e.g. (untested sorry)

```
add_post_meta( $post->ID, '_ggowlccpy_merchant_ref', $ggowlccpy_order_id);

$meta_query = new WP_Meta_Query(array(
                  meta_key = '_ggowlccpy_merchant_ref',
                  meta_value = $ggowlccpy_order_id,
                  compare = '='));
$orders = $wpdb->get_results($meta_query->get_sql( 'post', $wpdb->posts, 'ID' ));
```

It won't be possible to match the existing serialized value: you're base64-encoding it to obscure the value in the database. (At least I guess this is to obscure it: you don't generally need to base64-encode the output of PHP serialize value.) If this wasn't base64-encoded then you could e.g. serialize the order ID and then search for _ggowlccpy_refund_details_get values that are LIKE (i.e. contain as a substring) the serialized order ID, then deserialize all of the results and check each one for merchant_ref = order ID until you find the correct one. However if you do need to query by this then I think a separate new post_meta value is easier and better.